# Redis cache breaks after env change

Tags: laravel, redis

After changing my `APP_ENV` from `local` to `production` I'm getting this error on my site?

```
ReflectionException (-1)
Class cache does not exist

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:752
```

On the stack trace, I see the following which I'm assuming is causing this problem:

```
$handler = $this->createCacheHandler('redis');
```

As soon as I revert back to `local` on my `APP_ENV` everything goes back to normal? or if I change `SESSION_DRIVER` from `redis` to `file` it appears to fix it?

I've also gone ahead and dumped the full stack trace which can be seen  [here](https://gist.github.com/InkedCurtis/e3f7ff073818900817c9e5fdedf5463a)

Comment: Are you testing local and production on the same system? Check your composer dev dependencies and verify, if there is anything, which should be available not only in dev...

Comment: Try php artisan cache:clear and composer dump-autoload

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am having the exact problem with Laravel 5.5